# How can I condense this simple "if" line of code?

Tags: python

I have a line of code in my program that checks if a number is divisible by several numbers.

However, the way I currently have it is extremely inefficient and ugly.

It currently looks like:

`if(x % 1 == 0 and x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0)` and so forth for several other numbers. I was hoping someone could teach me how I could take out the long `and` chain and help me replace it with something that makes more sense so instead it will look like:

`if(x % a[1,2,3] == 0)`

Is this possible and if so can anyone please help me?

**EDIT: The x % 1 == 0, x % 2 == 0, etc.. Is not the full equation. I am checking far more than % 1,2, and 3. I am looking for a solution that can take say.. 1 through 15. That is why I am not using x % 6.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if all(x % k == 0 for k in [1, 2, 3]):
    print 'yay'
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, however is there a way I can condense things further say if I wanted 10+ numbers in there is there I a way I could do so without writing "for k in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,..]):" ?

Comment: @Scarecrow use `in range(1, n+1)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm terribly sorry for coming off as so foolish, but I'm having trouble implementing that. Could you perhaps write out an example of it in use for me?

Comment: @Scarecrow `if not any(x % k for k in range(1, 11)):` will check against every integer from one to ten inclusive.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah! I feel stupid now haha, it was a lot more straight forward than I expected. Thank you! I understand now. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 1*2*3
if(x%n == 0):
    #do stuff
```

Will work for any set of prime numbers.

Comment: as OP noted: 'so forth for several other numbers'. Of course you can multiple all, but OP asked about general technique, what if condition was `x % y != 1`?

Comment: My bad, answer changed.

Comment: @Wooble Usually I prefer readability, unless this becomes bottleneck

Comment: Here you are, now it's `n`

Comment: now much better ;o) and you could use 'product', btw.

Answer (score 0):

for 1 through 15,you can use `all(x % (k+1) == 0 for k in range(15))`. for example::

```
>>> for x in range(10):
...  if all(x % (k+1) == 0 for k in range(3)): #checks weather x is divisible by 1,2,3
...   print x
... 
0
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lcm = LCM of set of number to divide i.e. (1,2,3....)
if(x % lcm == 0)
   //pass
```